# maximise $(1-x)^{n-1}x - x^n$ subject to $0\le x\le 1/n$, where n is a natural number

Tags: analysis, optimization, asymptotics

Let $n$ be a natural number. Define a function $f(x) := (1-x)^{n-1}x - x^n$, where $0\le x\le 1/n$. How do I maximise this function?

From numerical experiments, the maximiser $x^*$ is very close to $1/n$ (say when $n \ge 8$). I need only the asymptotics of $f(x^*)$ for large $n$.

Comment: Edited for simpler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x) = (1-x)^{n-1}x - x^n \implies f'(x)=(1-x)^{n-2} (1-n x)-n x^{n-1}$$

Expanding $f'(x)$ as a series around $x=\frac{1}{n}$ gives
$$f'(x)=-n^{2-n}-\frac{\left((n-1)^n+(n-1)^3\right) n^{3-n}}{(n-1)^2}\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\right)$$ from which
$$\color{blue}{x_* =\frac 1 n \Bigg[1 -\frac{1}{(n-1) \left(1+(n-1)^{n-3}\right)} \Bigg]}\tag 1$$

Some results for small values of $n$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 n & \text{Max}_{\text{est}} & x_{\text{est}} &\text{Max}_{\text{calc}} & x_{\text{calc}} \\
 3 & 0.1250000000 & 0.2500000000  & 0.1250000000& 0.2500000000 \\
 4 & 0.1022041227 & 0.2291666667  & 0.1022044240& 0.2296052348 \\
 5 & 0.0816116932 & 0.1970588235  & 0.0816116941& 0.1970852069 \\
 6 & 0.0669582639 & 0.1664021164  & 0.0669582639& 0.1664024424 \\
 7 & 0.0566515658 & 0.1428387855  & 0.0566515658& 0.1428387874 \\
 8 & 0.0490869284 & 0.1249989376  & 0.0490869284& 0.1249989376 \\
 9 & 0.0433049244  & 0.1111110581 & 0.0433049244& 0.1111110581 \\
 10 & 0.0387420488 & 0.0999999977 & 0.0387420488& 0.0999999977
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, you can neglect the $1$ (except in powers) and get
$$\color{red}{x_* \sim \frac 1 n (1-n^{2-n})}\tag 2$$ which, for $n=10$ will give $x_*=0.099999999$.

Concerning $f(x_*)$, before any simplification

$$f(x_*)=\frac{(n-1)^n+(n-2) (n-1)^2}{\left((n-1)^n+(n-1)^3\right) n} \left(1-\frac{(n-1)^n+(n-2) (n-1)^2}{\left((n-1)^n+(n-1)^3\right) n}\right)^{n-1}-$$
$$\left(\frac{(n-1)^n+(n-2) (n-1)^2}{\left((n-1)^n+(n-1)^3\right) n}\right)^n$$

Neglecting again the $1$ and $2$ (except in powers) gives
$$\color{red}{f(x_*)=\frac 1 n \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}-n^{-n} \sim \frac 1 n \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}\quad \to \quad \frac e n}$$

Comment: There are ones one can neglect and ones one cannot neglect :), $\lim_{n \to \infty} (n - 1)^n/n^n \neq 1$.

Comment: @Maxim. You are right ! I edit

Comment: what is the asymptotic value of f(x*)?

Comment: why is x* asymptotically equal to the approximation of the root of f'(x) after one iteration of Newton's Method? Why does one iteration give the correct asymptotic?

Comment: @ColinTan. I used what you did observe (which is more than true). We could do the same with Halley or Householder methods or even with Taylor series. If I have time, I shall update.

Comment: dear Claude, thank you so much for the details and spending time on my problem.

Comment: @ColinTan. You are welcome ! The problem was interesting (I am still trying to improve). By the way, may be you could accept my answer in order other users know that it is a valid solution. Cheers :-)

Comment: I actually am of the opinion that $f(x^\ast) = \frac{1}{(n - 1)} \left((1 - \frac{1}{n})^n + \frac{\Theta(1)}{n^n}\right)$.

Comment: @ColinTan. I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would help but ...

```
SCIP Status        : problem is solved [optimal solution found]
Solving Time (sec) : 0.12
Solving Nodes      : 45
Primal Bound       : +1.25000772705644e-01 (26 solutions)
Dual Bound         : +1.25000772705644e-01
Gap                : 0.00 %

primal solution (original space):
=================================

objective value:                    0.125000772705644
i1                                                  2   (obj:0)
x0                                  0.250018487408352   (obj:0)
x2                                  0.125000772705644   (obj:1)
x3                                                0.5   (obj:0)
x5                                                  1   (obj:0)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).